# copy the output of a command into 2 log files in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, logging, scripting

Scenario in batch scripting:

There is file1.log and file2.log

set file1 = D:\Test\file1.log

set file2 = D:\Test\file2.log

and there is a command

if exist "%abc%" xcopy %abc% "D:\Test" /Y >> %file1%

I want the same command output to also be copied to file2

I tried
Type %file1% > %file2% ----> but then I lose the data in file2 and

Type %file1% >> %file2% ----> generates lot of duplicate data

Is there a way to do it simultaneously? Can the output of the command be stored in a variable and later written into the 2 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if exist "%abc%" (
 xcopy %abc% "D:\Test" /Y > %file3%
 type %file3%>>%file1%
 type %file3%>>%file3%
 del %file3%
)
```

or

```
if exist "%abc%" (for /f "delims=" %%r in ('xcopy %abc% "D:\Test" /Y') do echo %%r>>%file1%&echo %%r>>%file2%
```

spring immediately to mind.